# Extracting certain indices from a numpy matrix

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a Matrix of values and an array of indices and I would like to go through each row of the matrix and only take the value corresponding to the index in my indices array.

So for row 1 in matrix, I take the value corresponding to the first element in my array.

```
Mat = [[0. 4. 4. 4.]
      [2. 8. 8. 2.]
      [7. 7. 7. 7.]
      ...
      [5. 5. 5. 5.]
      [7. 7. 7. 7.]
      [2. 6. 6. 6.]]

arr = [0 0 3 ... 0 0 3]
```

So I want the 0th value from the first row, the 0th from the second and so on and I want to save that in a vector at the end.

```
np.take(Mat,arr,axis=1,out=y)
```

But this does not work and I get a Matrix in return and not a vector. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be accomplished using the [`choose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.choose.html) method:

```
np.choose(indices, matrix.T)
```

Comment: But the `choose` docs discourages this use, even though it works - up to a certain size (32 choices).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [integer array indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing) for rows and columns:

```
res = mat[np.arange(len(mat)), arr]
```

Here's a demo:

```
mat = np.array([[0, 4, 3, 1],
                [2, 8, 8, 2],
                [1, 2, 3, 4],
                [5, 4, 3, 2],
                [4, 3, 2, 1],
                [2, 5, 6, 4]])

arr = np.array([0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 3])

res = mat[np.arange(len(mat)), arr]

print(res)

array([0, 2, 4, 5, 4, 4])
```